# Enforce JSON type on serialization

Tags: swift

I have the following:

```
/// Reads local JSON file
func readJSONFromFile<T : Decodable>(modelToDecode: T.Type, fileName: String) throws -> T {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "json")!
    
    let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    // Getting data from JSON file using the file URL
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl, options: .mappedIfSafe)
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
    
    return json
}
```

How can I explicitly say on the last line before the return, the type I want to be decoded? For examplem let's say the type is `MyModel123`. I tried  `as! T` at the end but give me an error `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

Comment: You are using the wrong decoder. You should be using JSONDecoder

Comment: alright, let me try it @LeoDabus

Comment: Yep, that worked with `let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)` Do you want to post the answer or I do? @LeoDabus

Comment: Feel free to post it. Note that you don't have to pass the type `modelToDecode` in your method signature. You can simply explicitly set the resulting type. Btw `Bundle` has a `url(forResource)` method

Comment: Yeah but I did it that way because of scalability, in case I need to use another model @LeoDabus

Comment: it doesnt matter `func readJSONFromFile<T: Decodable>(fileName: String)` should be enought

Comment: maybe I'm not understanding, how would you write it then? @LeoDabus

Comment: `let result: WhatEver = try readJSONFromFile(fileName: "fileName")`

Comment: That was an amazing code reduction! Love it! Thanks! @LeoDabus

Comment: Note that passing a type is sometimes needed but these situations are rare and only when your data model is inside a class hierarchy. This won't be a problem with structs.

Comment: Noted, so far everything I'm doing is compatible :) @Sulthan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to use `JSONDecoder` instead of `JSONSerialization`

Here's how I change the last line:

```
let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
```